# term for distance preserving up to scale

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

Is there a common/established term for distance preserving up to scale?

E.g. Consider two Riemannian manifolds $M \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ and $N \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with metrics $g_M$ and $g_N$ inherited from their respective ambient Euclidean spaces, and let
$\mathcal{F}((M,g_M), (N,g_N)) = \{f:M\to N | g_M=f^*g_N\}/\sim$
where $f\sim g$ if there exists some constant $c\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f = cg$.

Is there a name for elements of $\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: This may sound a bit awkward to a geometer -- I'd argue it's a natural quotient space to discuss in certain areas of machine learning, where we're typically learning a map from some subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ to a Euclidean space and trying to preserve some type of information/structure while we do it.

Answer (score 1):

The correct term is *homothetic*.

Comment: This notation is a bit foreign to me, but the line "the image of every line L is a line parallel to L" makes this sound a bit more strict than what I'm looking for (e.g. the set described in the question includes rotations).

Comment: Within Riemannian geometry, the term *homothetic* means that two metrics are proportional; i.e. $g_1=cg_2$ for some positive constant $c$.  This is different from the usual meaning of the term in Euclidean geometry.  Given your setting, the former interpretation is the natural one.

Comment: Whoops, my previous comment was referring to [the homothetic transform wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation).